# Execute second statement if the first one holds

Tags: php, codeigniter

If a directory does not exist, i create the directory and save a file, i can also just save a file if the directory exists. One file should be created at a time not all at the same time as the code below does. If the first file is created now then the next should only be created when the function is called. The files are Named R1,R2....Rn. How can I achieve this, This creates them all at the same time

```
$fileName1=$fileName1='somedir/'.$thedir.'/'.$thefile.'_R1.xlsx';

...

if (!dir($dirName)) 
{
    mkdir('somedir/' . thedir, 0777);
    $objWriter->save($fileName);
}

if (dir($dirName) && (!file_exists($fileName))) 
{
    $objWriter->save($fileName);
} 

if (dir($dirName) && file_exists($fileName)) 
{
    $objWriter->save('somedir/' . $thedir . '/' . $thefile . '_R1.xlsx');
}

if (dir($dirName) && file_exists($fileName1)) 
{
    $objWriter->save('somedir/' . $thedir . '/' . $thefile . '_R2.xlsx');
}

...
```

Comment: You need [is_dir()](http://php.net/is_dir) function, [dir()](http://php.net/dir) does not behave the way you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!is_dir($dir))
  mkdir($dir, 0777);

$suffixes = array('_R1.xlsx', '_R2.xlsx');
foreach($suffixes as $suffix) {
  $fileName = $dir.'/' . $thefile . $suffix;
  if (! file_exists($fileName)) {
    $objWriter->save($fileName);
    break;
  }
}
```

You have to add error handling, and note that just checking for a file can create concurrency issues (two processes trying both seeing that the file doesn't exist and try to create it).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked like a charm. How do i make the first file without a suffix then the subsequent to be R1....Rn

Comment: I figured that out finally, i don't have to use the suffix in the first value of the array

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `[is_dir][1]` function to check if a folder exists.

Check out this code - a bit of a rework from yours

```
$fileName1=$fileName1='somedir/'.$thedir.'/'.$thefile.'_R1.xlsx';
....

// Directory does not exist - create it
if (!is_dir($dirName)) 
{
    mkdir('somedir/' . thedir, 0777);
    $objWriter->save($fileName);
}

// Directory exists
if (is_dir($dirName))
{
    // File does not exist - create it
    if (!file_exists($fileName))) 
    {
        $objWriter->save($fileName);
    } 

    // Check one more time if the file exists
    if (file_exists($fileName))) 
    {
        $objWriter->save('somedir/' . $thedir . '/' . $thefile . '_R1.xlsx');
        $objWriter->save('somedir/' . $thedir . '/' . $thefile . '_R2.xlsx');
    }
}

.......
```